# Best way to define a Customized authorization policy

Tags: mongodb, security, authorization, opensso, data-security

I am developing a project with MongoDB, I have a scenario, so that I can restrict the visibility of data to the user based on their role, for example if I have a document of the form:

```
{
   "testme1":"fooo",
  "testme2":"foobar"
}
```

A user with role "admin" can see both "testme1" and "testme2", whereas "guest" can see only "testme2". What is the best way to define these authorization rule dynamically, so that my wrapper api should fetch the data only as per the rule. My approach of doing is to give the user a web "UI" to define a rule and based on his declaration keep a "XML" file in my server. Please let me know if someone has a better Idea,also if their is some Database level approach to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an authorization standard that exists which you can use to define your authorization policies. This standard is called XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. It implements an authorization model called attribute-based access control (ABAC). You can read up on both topics here:

- NIST's page on [attribute-based access control](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/) (ABAC)
- OASIS [extensible access control markup language](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) (XACML)

XACML defines an architecture with the notion of:

- a policy decision point (PDP),
- a policy enforcement point (PEP), and
- a policy information point (PIP).

In the typical flow, the PEP protects your data / service / API. The PEP would send an authorization request to the PDP:

- Can user Alice view record #123?

The PDP would turn to the PIP to retrieve missing attributes e.g. the user's role and clearance as well as resource attributes e.g. the sensitivity of data, a whitelist or blacklist... Based on the new information, the PDP can reach a decision: *Permit* or *Deny*. Access is allowed or blocked.

With XACML there is no limit to the richness of the authorization policies. I work for a company, [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com), that implements XACML, and our solutions are used in manufacturing, healthcare, banking to secure access to sensitive data in a dynamic way (e.g. managers can edit documents that they own).

XACML enables externalized authorization that is managed centrally. It also enables what I like to call *any-depth authorization* meaning that you can apply XACML to web APIs, business logic, presentation UIs, as well as databases.

HTH

Comment: Barbarossa is their any good tool that can generate XACML file for my rule?

Comment: Also my scenario is not to make decision like permit,or deny but to make decision like "what columns" from a row should the user be given access based on role , can this situation be addressed by XACML

Comment: You can achieve "reverse querying" with XACML. I call reverse querying questions such as "what can I do?" or "who can view this resources?" or in your case "which columns can I display?"

Comment: To generate XACML, have a look at the ALFA plugin for Eclipse. It is a free tool that will let you generate XACML using pseudocode.

Comment: I tried doing that in Axiomatics website but didn't got any link for download after registration, nor found it in eclipse market

Comment: I already tried the above link and registered myself, but I only saw a message "We got your message and will contact you soon"

Comment: Is it possible to get "Axiomatics" "java api" jar for testing purpose?

Comment: can I develop my own PDP with Axiomatic api?